# error al ejecutar npm run watch con laravel

Tags: npm, laravel-8

Estoy teniendo un error al ejecutar npm run watch con laravel 8
al ejecutar me aparece este error:

anteriormente me salia este error
"cross-env" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo y ejecute estos comandos:

npm uninstall cross-env
npm install cross-env --no-bin-links
npm run watch

esta seria mas mi configuracion de package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "alpinejs": "^2.8.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.2.1",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.3",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "node-sass": "^6.0.1"
    }
```

al ejecutar npm run watch no llega a compilar y me aparece lo siguiente

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                               10:22:41

 error  in ./resources/css/app.css

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
    at Processor.normalize (c:\laragon\www\projet1\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:153:15)
    at new Processor (c:\laragon\www\projet1\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:56:25)
    at postcss (c:\laragon\www\projet1\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:55:10)
    at c:\laragon\www\projet1\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:140:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at c:\laragon\www\projet1\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at c:\laragon\www\projet1\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at c:\laragon\www\projet1\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (c:\laragon\www\projet1\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at c:\laragon\www\projet1\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:208:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: El mensaje te dice "Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users". ¿Lo leíste?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que instalar postcss que es un plugin requerido de tailwindcss

```
npm i postcss
```

Comment: ya probe con ese comando para instalar postcss. Me aparece el mismo error